# Why the probability density value of pandas is too large

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am using pandas to draw probability density, and my data are described as follow:

```
count    636149.000000
mean          3.040828
std           3.752975
min           0.000000
25%           0.050000
50%           1.050000
75%           5.050000
max          59.200000
```

My code as follows:

```
df['data'].hist(bins=1000,density=1)
plt.show()
```

The results are shown as shown in the picture.

[image]

I wonder why my values has reached 5, and should not normally be less than 1?How should I correct it?

Comment: the data description says only 50% values are less than one, I see nothing wrong with the code

Comment: Values do not necessarily need to be less than one, the total area under the curve has to be one.

Comment: @MassoudHosseinali Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in one of the comments, values not necessarily need to be 1 at max, but the area of all the bins together should be 1.

As you can read in the [doc](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html%20'doc'):

> density : boolean, optional
>
> If True, the first element of the return tuple will be the counts normalized to form a probability density, i.e., the area (or integral) under the histogram will sum to 1. This is achieved by dividing the count by the number of observations times the bin width and not dividing by the total number of observations. If stacked is also True, the sum of the histograms is normalized to 1.

The area of 1 bin is (obviously) the frequency times the bin-width. Since you have 1000 bins and a range of `[0,59.2]`. Your bin width is `0.0592`, so that results in quite small areas per bin and thus summing all 1000 'small' areas gives an area under the curve of 1.

You could check this with [`np.histogram`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html).

Comment: The question is quite simple: somebody wants to have normalized plot like df.value_counts(normalized=True), while this option doesnt achieve the result with just using(df.value.hist(bins=n,density=1) while
the answer doesnt tell how to fix parameter of density to achieve expected performance